# How to open a database in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, listener

I have created a class to manage a SQLite database. Part of its code is as follows:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "name";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public Database (Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Then I have created another class, which is an SMS listener (extending `BroadcastReceiver`). Inside of this class I cannot create a database with the following command:

```
db = new Database(this);
```

because I get this error message:

```
The constructor Database(SmsListener) is undefined
```

How should I change the code to be able to open a database connection from inside the `SmsListener` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `onReceive()` method in the `BroadcastReceiver` gets a `Context` passed, use that.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    db = new Database(context);
    //more stuff
}
```

Also be aware that inside a `BroadcastReceiver`, you are only guaranteed 10 seconds of execution time, after that, Android may kill your Receiver. So be quick with what you're doing and if the database operation is lengthy, consider using a separate `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Database` constructor takes a `Context` as its only parameter. The error message tells you that `this` is an `SmsListener` which does not extend `Context`.